# Why does eclipse hide private members in outline view of Java?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I'm doing android development using eclipse version 3.7.1 (Indigo) with Android's ADT version 16.0.1.  I've also loaded Android source files into my SDK so that I can browse through the source.  I'm finding that when I open an android file in the editor the outline view doesn't show any of the private members that are in the source file.  I don't understand the connection mechanism between the ".class" file (embedded in a jar file) and the ".java" source files but the editor claims to be showing me the VideoView.class file (for example) even though I also have the VideoView.java file in my SDK.

Also, I don't have any of the filtering/hiding buttons selected in the outline view and there are no @* directives in the source.  Is there some preference at play here?

Answer (score 3):

There is a preference that hides non-public members - it's controlled by the button in the Outline tolbar that looks like a green dot. Toggling it might fix the problem.

Comment: Thanks Russell but, as I mentioned above, I don't have any of those buttons selected.  I toggled "Hide Non-Public Members" button just to make sure.

Answer (score 1):

android.jar is stripped down to just it's public API.
Things marked private and things with the @hide javadoc tag are gone. Eclipse doesn't know about them.
If you remove the source attachment you won't see them either.